# unable to connect wired network and wifi in newly installed ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless, network-manager, internet, wired

I just have installed ubuntu 18.04 (single operating system) with Intel I9-10900K CPU in MSI 490 unify motherboard through a GPU (Asus Video NVIDIA GTX1650 O4G TUF Gaming). I am unable to connect internet through ethernet cable and wi-fi as well. There is no option for wired network (only VPN and proxy network are displayed) and Wi-Fi shows no adapter found. The internet cable works in other computers, though tried with different cables also. I am new in Linux, but i tried most of the suggestion available on this forum and YouTube. Nothing has worked so far. The driver and utilities supplied by MSI in CD are not getting installed. Ubuntu just open all the files instead of installation of executable files in CD. Any support will be greatly appreciated.

[image: commands outcome]
Edit:, after trying to install driver update as per suggestion , i do not find any solution. it says check old driver and unload it etc.[output after running autorun.sh file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzhM7.jpg)
{

```
This is the Linux device driver released for RealTek RTL8125 2.5Gigabit Ethernet controllers with PCI-Express interface.
```

```
- Kernel source tree (supported Linux kernel 2.6.x and 2.4.x)
- For linux kernel 2.4.x, this driver supports 2.4.20 and latter.
- Compiler/binutils for kernel compilation
```

Unpack the tarball :
        # tar vjxf r8125-9.aaa.bb.tar.bz2

```
Change to the directory:
    # cd r8125-9.aaa.bb

If you are running the target kernel, then you should be able to do :

    # ./autorun.sh  (as root or with sudo)

You can check whether the driver is loaded by using following commands.

    # lsmod | grep r8125
    # ifconfig -a

If there is a device name, ethX, shown on the monitor, the linux
driver is loaded. Then, you can use the following command to activate
the ethX.

    # ifconfig ethX up

    ,where X=0,1,2,...}
```

EDIT : At the end, when nothing has worked smoothly, i installed the updated version of Ubuntu 20.04, and now all the problems are fixed and solved. PC working nicely and automatically updating the system through wired network. Wi-Fi also connected.

Comment: 18.04 is likely too old for your hardware, so does not understand how to use them. Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of `sudo lshw -c network`, `sudo lspci` and `sudo lsusb`? This will show network and hardware information about your computer that may make it easier to offer a solution 

Comment: okay, i will update it as per your suggestion and then let you know, thanks

Comment: Hi @matigo, I have edit the post and attached an image with the output

Comment: The drivers for the Ethernet device were added to Linux kernel 5.9, so anything earlier will need [the 2.5G Ethernet driver from here](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software). Be sure to follow the instructions in the README file to install the driver correctly. You may need to install the `build-essential` package first, though, which is a challenge without a network connection 

Comment: yes i am trying the same but i do not understand why its not reading my the downloaded files in pen drive. i am following read me file. But still the command lines does not seems to work or i do not understand these commands how to properly write and execute them.

Comment: hi @matigo, for example <Quick install with proper kernel settings>
 Unpack the tarball :
  # tar vjxf r8125-9.aaa.bb.tar.bz2, so should i start my command with # or directly starting from sudo and copying all this content in command line,

Comment: Start from `sudo`.

Comment: @matigo, unable to figure out, what's going wrong. I have edited it again with updated outcome.

Comment: @matigo,..i finally installed the Ubuntu 20.04, and now all the problems are fixed and solved. PC working nicely and automatically updating the system through wired network. Wi-Fi also connected. thanks for the valuable support.